# JQuery UI Dialog not displaying in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dialog

Hi I have a problem with the dialog not showing in IE

Heres the modified code:

```
function setSpinnerDialog(text) {
var spinner = $('<div></div>').html(text +
"<img  id='loadingImage' src='../../Content/images/spinner.gif'/>").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 35,
    width: 160
});
return spinner;}


$('#imgVisitorEscortIds,#imgVisitingCardIds').click(function (e) {

 $spinnerDialog = setSpinnerDialog("loading... ");
 $spinnerDialog.dialog('open');

 //create list 
  $('#' + listId).selectBox();

//show dialog of list


 //close spinner
  $spinnerDialog.dialog('close');
```

Whilst the select is being generated (potentially 100's of names) a loading dialog is meant to display.  This happens in all browsers but not IE.

Any suggestions

Cheers

Comment: Try moving your DOM ready event to the end of your js file.. Some what similar issue happened with me recently and moving that fixed the issue...

Comment: Are you missing some code? your function `setSpinnerDialog` does not return the object and does not close.

Comment: try to set timeout before calling setSpinnerDialog and opening the dialog

Comment: Is `selectBox()` synchronous?

Comment: The dialog does not expose a timeout property

Comment: As far as I can tell async.  The script works fine in all other browsers just IE is causing the issue

Comment: If it's asynchronous then the dialog would appear and then be destroyed immediately, regardless of browser.  I'll propose a solution as an answer because I have a suggestion that I *think* will resolve your problem.

Comment: One more thing if I test for isOpen using a alert the loading dialog is displayed before the card list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had issues of a similar nature before, but never this exact problem.  I've found that IE can sometimes try to be a little *too* efficient and can spoil things.  Try putting a slight interval in before you get the select items, just to make sure that the dialog has time to show....

```
//create list 
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#' + listId).selectBox();
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks - as an alternative solution it works.Just display the cardList immediately and not bother with the loading dialog.  Just got to render the html nicely now

Comment: If you ever have issues with IE trying to do things at the same time and some of them appearing to not work, add a delay!  It's the first thing I try when IE fails.  Glad it helped :)

Comment: As a further update I ended up using mousedown and mouseup events to display the loading dialog before the showing the card list.